# How to integrate and publish PHP app on Google Apps Marketplace v2?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-apps-marketplace

Having searched extensively on Stackoverflow as well Google, this question seems a lot of people need an answer for. Here is where I stand, and what needs to be achieve:

I have a standalone PHP application that makes use of Google Admin SDK and also has a database under the hood. I install it manually for each domain which wants to use it by copying files and replicating the database. All fine so far.

Next, I am trying to understand how to integrate and publish my PHP app on GAM v2 so as it can be:

- installed by any domain administrator for entire domain so that users of the domain do not need to authorize the app at user level
- each time the application instance is installed by a domain administrator, the entire set of files and database are "cloned" at a new location (on my server) that is specific to the domain being installed
- I do not want to use Google Apps Engine or Cloud service to host this app

Can anyone please enlighten how to achieve this?

Thanks

PS: I have tried [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/building) but didn't really understand fully; can someone help?

Comment: It would be helpful to explain specifically where you are getting stuck. Any errors? etc.

Comment: I am stuck at the process flow itself. The app works well but integrating it with GApps to allow self-installation is where I am stuck. It appears that when you create a new project in developer console, you must host it on Google Apps Engine? Is it even possible to host all code on your shared server and offer universal navigation integration and self-installation?